# Updating existing XmlNode into a self closing XML tag

Tags: c#, xml

I have this scenario where I would want to replace an existing XML element eg:

```
<Car xsi:nil='true'></Car>
```

into

```
<Car xsi:nil='true'/>
```

I want to accomplish the above by using only XmlNode. Is this possible?

Comment: Why?  The only thing it does is reduce the size of the file.

Comment: @jdweng Hi yes understood too. Its just to standardise our XML docs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    Dim xml As New XmlDocument()
    xml.LoadXml(<Car></Car>.ToString())

    For Each n As XmlElement In xml
        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(n.Value) Then n.IsEmpty = True
    Next
```

Comment: Hi, is there anyway to do it through XmlNode? Thanks.

Comment: I've updated it to using the System.Xml classes. I presume this is what you're meaning by XmlNode.

Comment: I think it is a different class albeit it being part of the System.Xml family. There is no IsEmpty property for XmlNode.

Comment: XmlElement derives from XmlNode. XmlNode is just an abstract concept of a node. So you are technically using XmlNode. Why do you need it to be only XmlNode?

Comment: You are right. Apologies didn't noticed the relation between them previously. It works now. Thanks!